# What is the best strategy in symfony 3 to handle internationalization?

Tags: php, internationalization, translation, symfony, strategy-pattern

I was wondering if there was a best way of internationalization using keys .

I already know how to use basics of translation in symfony 3.

```
hello.world: 'Hello world !'
```

But i read this article : http://obtao.com/blog/2013/06/how-to-organize-your-translations-in-symfony/
And this seems to be great at first site, but i was asking myself what is the most common way to translate for a big project

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Localization Best Practices? gettext?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790952/php-localization-best-practices-gettext)

Comment: @eldelshell right