# iOS App Localisation Best Practices And Placeholders

Tags: ios, swift, localization

We're currently at the stage of looking at localising our app in to multiple languages now that the general concepts of the app have been decided. This is something I want to ensure is done correct from the start to lower the risk of headaches in the future.

The app targets iOS 7 and above, uses storyboards, and is written in Swift.

**Storyboards**

When working with a storyboard (or a xib), what's the best way to mark a UI element as "not to be translated"? For example, I have a placeholder string for a user's display name (`Display Name`), which will be replaced by a users display name at run time. This display name will not be localised, but neither should the string "Display Name". Is there a method of not having a UI element's value automatically put in to the `strings` file? If not, is going in to that file and manually removing strings I don't want localising a sustainable option?

**Strings In Code**

I'm using the Swift function `NSLocalizedString` with the `key` and `comment` parameters. Some places I've seen say to set the key to be a unique id based on the context (e.g., `intro.login-button-text`), while others seem to just put the full string in the default language (e.g., `Login`). I like the idea of the unique ids for the key, but would this not go against the idea of the "base" language?

**Exporting**

Xcode 6's "Export For Localization" option seems very useful for getting the correct format of file to be sent to translators. However, as mentioned previously, placeholder text does not need to be translated. Should these placeholders be removed from the exported `xliff` or the `strings` file prior to export?

Comment: Another question is with formats. E.g. is it better to localise `"%1$@ is online!"` where `%1$@` is the name of the user or have the format to be `"%1$@ %2$@"` where `%1$@` is the name of the user and  `%2$@` is the localised string `"is online!"`. I think the first is more descriptive to the localiser. But localising formats seems a bit off especially if you are working on a cross-platform app.

Comment: @Reggian you need to use the first alternative. In many languages the name might come last or in the middle of the sentence. The translator need to have the ability to move the name part of the text around.

Answer (score 2):

Looking for the the same questions myself. Hope this will help you and others. Also I would recommend to have some kind of tool to organize the xliff/string files

**Storyboards:**

I've seen developers putting non translating texts in storyboard with extra parentheses. i.e. {Display name}.

By using this you can see by the translation itself if it needs to be translated or not. We use oneskyapp.com and can select to hide those translations and they will be hidden for each import of that key.

**Strings in Code**

By following this thread they suggest to use keywords.
[Best practice for key values in translation files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654056/best-practice-for-key-values-in-translation-files)

**Exporting**

I cannot find a way to have some translations automatically removed when exporting. Off course you can put the views which has dynamic fields in different XIB/storyboards and decide not to translate those.

Again a tool like onskyapp.com can help you with this.

**Formats**

As of context with the field is important and a translation can be different when it is followed by i.e. a users name I would go for "%1$@ is online!"