# How to set python gettext translations to source language

Tags: python, gettext

I have this piece of code for translations:

```
translations = gettext.translation(
    locale_language,
    localedir="gui/locale",
    languages=[locale_language]
)
translations.install()
```

Where `locale_language` can be `"en"` (source language (`msgid`s)) or `"es"` (translated language (`msgstr`s))

I need to have `en.mo` and `es.mo` to switch languages correctly, but since the source language is English, `en.mo` is not filled. I have to do it this way to run previous code when language changes.

I was wondering if there is a better way to do this, i.e., without an empty `en.mo` (also above code would requiere an `if` checking if `locale_language == "en"`, but that is not the problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a never ending discussion whether the `msgid` should be the actual English string, or rather a "key" which will need to be translated to English as to any other language: look for instance at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216478/gettext-is-it-a-good-idea-for-the-message-id-to-be-the-english-text). And of course if you use key strings the `en.mo` file needs to be complete just like any other.

If however you want to use actual English strings as `msgid`s then you may simply avoid to install a translation for English, and perhaps define a dummy `_()` function like

```
def _(msg):
    return msg
```

This way you won't need a `en.mo` at all.

Comment: The dummy `_()` would be a problem in my code, since I'm using the same `_` across multiple files. Filling `en.mo` seems the best solution (and most tedious).